# Spark-cassandra pagination Query?

Tags: pagination, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I am query cassandra database using spark, is pagination possible with query. I am able to it with dataframe but it takes lot of time in case of large amount of data.  Is it possible to get data by specifying range of data to retreive. for example, in case of below given query

**"select * from flow"**

Can i alter the query in such a that i can get record from 50-100?